# How to specify two line label in iOS Attribute Inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uilabel

I am creating a View (i.e. I went to `New -> iOS -> User Interface -> View`). I want to have a two line UILabel in my View. But when I set the label's text as `Line one here this. \nAnd line 2`, the entire literal shows up in one line. Even though I specify that the label should have two lines. How do I make it two lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put \n in the text, but rather press `Alt/Option` + `Enter`

Comment: The property says `Line` and yes I have already set it to 2 in the Attribute Inspector. Also my post already said that. :)

Comment: Ok then. Don't put \n in the text, but rather press `Alt/Option` + `Enter`